# Finding numbers which are composed of the digits 2 and 5

Tags: permutations

How many numbers are there between $100$ and $1000$ including $100$ such that every digit is either $2$ or $5$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Can you answer the same question if we want integers between $10$ and $100$?

Comment: Do you mean divisible by 2 or 5?

Comment: No it means every digit in that number is either 2 or five

Comment: Titles such as "Finding the number of ways" do not describe the question accurately. A better title could be "Finding numbers which are composed of the digits 2 and 5".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have three $2$'s ($222$), two $2$'s and one $5$ ($225,252,522$), two $5$'s and one $2$ ($552,525,255$) and three $5$'s ($555$).

**ANSWER:** You will have $8$ such numbers.

**EDIT:** In standard permutation notation, you have $2$ choices for each digit, either $2$ or $5$. And in the given range, you will have $3$-digit numbers only. So total no. of numbers = $2 \times 2 \times 2 = 2^3 = 8$

Comment: Can you please express it in the standard form of permutations

Comment: I have updated my answer. See if it works.

Answer (score 1):

$222$ and $555$ can appear only once as their interchanged digits are the same.

Now,one $2$ and two $5$'s can be arranged in $3!-(1+1+1)=3$ ways.$(why?)$

Also,two $2$ and one $5$ can be arranged in $3!-(1+1+1)=3$ ways.$(why?)$

So,total=$5+3+3=8$ ways.

If you can't answer "why?" mention in the comment,I will help you.